# Cannot Plot Log

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I tried following command and it worked well (you can see the function is positive).

`Plot[1 - x^(2^(n + 1)^a - 2^n^a) /. {a -> 1 - 1/10, x -> 1 - 4^(-30)}, {n, 85, 98}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]`

But, I couldn't plot Log of this function:

`Plot[Log[1 - x^(2^(n + 1)^a - 2^n^a)] /. {a -> 1 - 1/10, x -> 1 - 4^(-30)}, {n, 85, 98}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]`

This shows only axes. I tried LogPlot, but it fails as well:

`LogPlot[1 - x^(2^(n + 1)^a - 2^n^a) /. {a -> 1 - 1/10, x -> 1 - 4^(-30)}, {n, 85, 98}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]`

Why Mathematica can't show log of this function?

Comment: The above is done in Mathematica 11.1. I tried in Mathematica 10.4, then `LogPlot` showed something but wrong. This function must vanish as x decrease but `LogPlot` showed that it approaches to 1 (`Plot[1 - x^(2^(n + 1)^a - 2^n^a)] showed vanishing property`).

Comment: If I replace `Log` by `RealExponent`, it works.  (`RealExponent[..]` is equivalent to `Log[Abs[..]]`, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(*  "11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"  *)
```

Use [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)

```
Clear[f]

f[n_, prec_: 25] := 
 Module[{rn = Rationalize[n, 0]}, 
  N[1 - x^(2^(rn + 1)^a - 2^rn^a) /. {a -> 1 - 1/10, x -> 1 - 4^(-30)}, prec]]

f[90.1]

(*  0.07970588475709084543825009  *)

Plot[f[n], {n, 85, 98}]
```

[image]

```
LogPlot[f[n], {n, 85, 98}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's a very simple but smart solution!

Answer (score 3):

In *Mathematica* 10.1.0 [`LogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogPlot.html) works:

```
LogPlot[1 - x^(2^(n + 1)^a - 2^n^a) /. {a -> 1 - 1/10, x -> 1 - 4^(-30)},
  {n, 85, 98}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

[image]

`Plot` however returns empty:

```
Plot[Log[1 - x^(2^(n + 1)^a - 2^n^a)] /. {a -> 1 - 1/10, x -> 1 - 4^(-30)},
  {n, 85, 98}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

[image]

A work-around is [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) and [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html):

```
ListLinePlot[
  Table[Log[1 - x^(2^(n + 1)^a - 2^n^a)] /. {a -> 1 - 1/10, x -> 1 - 4^(-30)},
    {n, 85`100, 98`100}],
  DataRange -> {85, 98}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This problem seems to be very sensitive to the implementation of Mathematica. `Plot` and `LogPlot` does not use the same method of evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

```
fun = 1 - x^(2^(n + 1)^a - 2^n^a) /. {a -> 1 - 1/10, x -> 1 - 4^(-30)}
```

[image]

For real `n` this monster formula returns `Indeterminate`:

```
Table[Log @ N[fun, 5], {n, 85, 98, 0.5}] // Short
```

> {Indeterminate, ..., Indeterminate}

But it produces results for integer and rational `n`:

```
Table[N[Log @ fun, 3], {n, 85, 98, 1/4}] // Short
```

[image]

which you can display with `ListLinePlot`

```
ListLinePlot @ Table[Log @ fun, {n, 85, 98, 1/4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Oh, this formula needs too big precision. I decided to use `Round[n, 1/100]` instead of n.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that works equally in versions 11.1 and 11.0:

```
Plot[Log[SetPrecision[
    1 - x^(2^(n + 1)^a - 2^n^a), $MachinePrecision] /. {a -> 1 - 1/10,
     x -> 1 - 4^(-30)}], {n, 85, 98}]
```

I wrapped the original function in [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html), which also allows me to omit the original `WorkingPrecision` option, so I think this is the simplest solution.

This also works with `LogPlot`.